# How to count total rows GROUP BY in MySQL the fastest

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a sample query

```
SELECT COUNT(counts) 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS counts
     FROM table AS table1
     LEFT JOIN table_2 as table2 ON table2.id = table1.pr_id
     WHERE table1.active = 1
     GROUP BY table1.column1) as t
```

I got the result

```
20563
```

The result was correct, but it was so slow, I had to wait up to 15 seconds for 1 query

15 seconds is too big, is there any way I can improve the speed as quickly as possible?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why do you use inner query for the left join rather than direct left join? It makes it slow.

Comment: @Strawberry i fixed it, important is that GROUP BY table1.coulum1

Comment: Akina is right that an outer join makes no sense in this context

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do.  Maybe you wanted `SUM(counts)`, but that probably does not make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

Inner counting makes no sense. So

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT table1.column1
  FROM table AS table1
  LEFT JOIN  ....
  WHERE ....
  ) as t
```

The index which matches joining condition and further WHERE / DISTINCT will improve.

PS. Check does `LEFT` makes sense, maybe `INNER JOIN` is enough.

Comment: Thank you! but I tried it, it was 13 seconds

Comment: I don't see that

Comment: @tranthaihoang Formally this is strange for simple cases. Your WHERE checks the values of right tables taking into account that they can be NULL, is it?